# XCode - How to reset/"delete" a mac os app run from Xcode (analog to deleting the app in the ios simulator)?

Tags: xcode, macos

When using the iOS Simulator, I can simply delete the app and re-run the app to start fresh. How is this done for mac os apps? I can't find it out. There is a folder for the project inside "DerivedData", but deleting this also messes with the entire project and I have to re-fetch all dependencies and stuff.

Thanks!

Comment: XCode > Product > Clean Build Folder ?

Comment: Tried this, but it doesn't seem to "remove" the app.

Comment: You're right, it doesn't really remove it, but it cleans the builder folder for the fresh builder. You will have no cache problems if that is the problem.

Comment: Yes, UserDefaults is one part of the problem. Another is an sqlite file for the database I'm using (YapDatabase). That's not deleted either. Do I have to delete all these manually every time?

Answer (score 4):

Had the same question, found the answer in another question on Stack Overflow: [Nicolas Miari and superfell's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27782318/resetting-mac-application-in-xcode) did the trick for me and my Mac Catalyst app:

> You can use the defaults command line tool to remove all the settings,
> you just need the bundle id of your app (which you can find in your
> Info.plist file), e.g. if your bundle id is "com.foo.barApp" then you
> can run this from a terminal shell:
>
> `defaults delete com.foo.barApp`

Comment: this doesn't delete data in userdefaults

Comment: It works for me. It deletes everything stored in userdefaults, just like a fresh installed app.

Answer (score 3):

For anyone who comes here later for solution:

1. install fd from homebrew: `brew install fd`
2. search for your data folder: `fd com.thisIsYour.bundleId`
   You should see something likes this:
   Library/Containers/B155E847-3026-484D-8CC1-165E3CA1E9CD/Data/Library/...
   Library/Containers/B155E847-3026-484D-8CC1-165E3CA1E9CD/Data/Library/...
   Library/Containers/B155E847-3026-484D-8CC1-165E3CA1E9CD/Data/Library/...
3. remove the folder: `rm -rf Library/Containers/B155E847-3026-484D-8CC1-165E3CA1E9CD`

Answer (score 1):

For everyone who uses **Core Data**. You can find the sqlite files at:

> /Users/[Your Username]/Library/Containers/[App Bundle Identifier]/Data/Library/Application Support/[App Name]/***.sqlite

For example:

/Users/John/Library/Containers/com.my.example/Data/Library/Application Support/Example/private.sqlite

And yes, you have to delete it yourself if necessary.

Note:

> If you use CloudKit at the same time, all data in the CloudKit Console
> should also be deleted beforehand. Otherwise these will be restored
> automatically.

Answer (score 0):

If the app is storing something at say `~/Library/Caches/yourapp` or `~/Library/Application Support/yourapp`, it's trivial to set up an Automator Service, or bash alias to clean them up.

`~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData` is meant for the Xcode project and the things *Xcode* creates, not the things that your *app* creates such as user preferences.

Alternatively, you can create a listener for a flag in the app itself like `--run-fresh` that can be set in scheme settings as launch argument. This flag will (if you code it) stop the app from looking into user data folder.

Comment: Hm, I can't find the app inside either of these folders. But this might be because YapDatabase stores it somewhere else on macOS.